# SSL connection reusing and caching with Android OkHttpClient

Tags: android, session, ssl, okhttp, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit and OkHttp to perform all network operations like GET, POST for both HTTP and HTTPS url. Everything is working fine but except that i have a requirement to reuse the sessions in order to reduce the Handshake timing process for each and every service calls. As of now the server takes more than 800ms to initiate the handshake between client and server for all the service calls.

**What I need:**

I have to reuse the SSLSessions in order to make handshake happen only for the first time or during specific intervals.

**Code I am using for SSL using Okhttp and Retrofit:**

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(baseURL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .client(getOkHttpClient(context, new OkHttpClient(), context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mysslcertificate)))
                            .build();

    retrofit.create(apiClass);


    public static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(Context context,OkHttpClient client, InputStream inputStream) {

        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                SSLContext sslContext = sslContextForTrustedCertificates(inputStream);


                if (sslContext != null) {
                   client = client.newBuilder()
                                        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()).build();


                    else {

                        CLog.i(Constants.LOG_TAG_HTTPLIBRARY,"GZip not done because it is not a Analytics data");

                        client = client.newBuilder()
                                .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()).build();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return client;
    }


     private static SSLContext sslContextForTrustedCertificates(InputStream in) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory e = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Collection certificates = e.generateCertificates(in);
            if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
            } else {
                char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
                KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
                int index = 0;
                Iterator keyManagerFactory = certificates.iterator();
                while (keyManagerFactory.hasNext()) {
                    Certificate trustManagerFactory = (Certificate) keyManagerFactory.next();
                    String sslContext = Integer.toString(index++);
                    keyStore.setCertificateEntry(sslContext, trustManagerFactory);
                }



                KeyManagerFactory var10 = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                var10.init(keyStore, password);
                TrustManagerFactory var11 = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                var11.init(keyStore);
                SSLContext var12 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                var12.init(var10.getKeyManagers(), var11.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

                return var12;
            }
        } catch (Exception var9) {
            var9.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**What I have tried:**

Since i couldn't find anything related to OkHttpClient but i tried referring few of the solutions like from the link as follows:

https://gist.github.com/codebutler/5565971

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html

But to be very frank nothing was helpful to me and I couldn't even find any relavant solutions for my requirement. In turn finally, I am completely stuck with this solution for the couple of weeks. Kindly help me to achieve my tasks through any of your tips and suggestions. Any piece of code or approach will be very useful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OkHttp supports SPDY and HTTP/2, which provide keep-alive support for SSL. Your server should be configured to support one of these, in which case AFAIK your SSL session reuse should happen automatically.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your reply. For SPDY and HTTP/2 support should i need to implement anything from the server side?. Also kindly assist me to reuse the session if my server doesn't support SPDY and HTTP/2. It would be very helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: "should i need to implement anything from the server side" -- that is a question of server configuration. Try Server Fault for those questions. "Also it would be very helpful if you assist me to reuse the session if my server doesn't support SPDY and HTTP/2" -- I highly doubt that it is possible.

Comment: @Chandru Even without SPDY or HTTP/2 you can cache the SSL sessions, but this has little to do with OkHTTP/Android. You have to configure that in your server (if it supports that) or find another web server that supports ssl session caching.

Comment: @Salem Thanks for your reply. Server side caching has been done. But still  it is taking some time for making handshake during each and every service call.

Comment: Make sure it is working with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html . If it is then it really can be a problem in the android side

Comment: @CommonsWare "should i need to implement anything from the client side" - This was the actual question. I misplaced the term server instead of client.

Comment: AFAIK, OkHttp should support SPDY and HTTP/2 without any special configuration.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot.